# Include other files in scope for program

Tags: haskell, cabal, leksah

I'm trying to make my first steps into the haskell world and for this I chose to use the leksah IDE.
However I'm not sure this is truly leksah specific but guess it might be more of a cabal / build problem.

Now I'm trying to solve [99 Haskell problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems) and for this I've opened a new workspace and created a new package.
This brings me basicaly to something like the following directory structure:

```
dist/
  +--- (here be dragons... a lot of hopefully unrelated files)
scr/
  +--- Main.hs
  +--- 01_lists.hs   (<- now that's what I want)
99problems.cabal
Setup.lhs
```

My Main.hs file looks like this:

```
module Main ( main ) where
main = putStrLn (show (myLast [1,2,3]) )
```

which blames me, that `Not in scope: myLast`.
I *can* fix this by writing the definition above the definition for `main = putStrLn ...` but what I want is to split this into different files and to include the files to my scope.

How is this done?

Guess it has something to do with `cabal` which leksah is using and I have to include it somehow, like I would do with `:load 01_lists.hs` in the REPL.
I've added the file in leksah under `Package -> Extra Files` but that alone didn't work out.

My environment is:

- Fedora 20
- Haskell-platform 2013.2.0.0 that is

  - leksah 0.12.1.3
  - cabal 1.16.0.2 (that is no `cabal repl` command which comes in [Cabal 1.18](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-21-Cabal-1-18.html) and would most likely help me)

I tend to believe it's an easy configuration problem with cabal.
Would anyone be so kind to lend me a hand with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `01_lists.hs` be `Euler01.hs` and start with `module Euler01`. Then in `Main.hs`, add at the top `import Euler01`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the concept of `module`s. What drove me off initially is that a `module` doesn't need to relate to a different file. I would have appreciated if you would have mentioned why you wanted to rename the file to `Euler01`, which I guess is because of the restriction for module name starting with a capital letter? What's more `leksah` didn't automatical recompile the module (as I suspected) and thus I searched for the old error before I hit that button again and actually saw that it worked out. In the end, it did work out. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Yep, sorry. A module must start with a capital letter and should be in a file with the same name, that's why I suggested the rename.

Comment: I think you mean to rename the file to `Euler01.hs`.